# functional programming in swift

Tags: swift, swift2

please, check my snippet, the question is there (my english is too bad to be able to explain my trouble by the words :))

```
func flip1<A, B, C>(f : ((A, B) -> C), _ b : B, _ a : A) -> C {
    return f(a, b)
}
flip1(-, 2, 1)      // -1
flip1(/, 2.0, 3.0)  // 1.5

// partialy curried version
func flip2<A, B, C>(f : (A, B) -> C, _ i : B, _ j : A) -> C {
    return f(j, i)
}

print(flip2(- , 2, 1))      // -1
print(flip2(/,2.0,3.0))   // 1.5
```

compiles without trouble, but how to use it???

```
// full curried version
// compiles without trouble, but how to use it???
func flip3<A, B, C>(f : A -> B -> C) -> B -> A -> C {
    return { b in { a in f(a)(b) } }
}

/*
* flip3(/)(2.0)(3.0)
*
* error: ambiguous reference to member '/'
* it meands there are more than one candidate for / function
*/

// we need curried version of /, let's define it
func curry<A,B,C>(f: (A, B) -> C) -> A -> B -> C {
    return { a in { b in f(a, b) } }
}

/*
* let divideUnknownType = curry(/)
* compiler still complain, as expected :-)
* error: ambiguous use of operator '/'
*/

// and then define the type of it
let divideDoubles: Double->Double->Double = curry(/)
let divideIntegers: Int->Int->Int = curry(/)
// :-)
print(flip3(divideDoubles)(2.0)(3.0)) // 1.5
print(flip3(divideDoubles)(2)(3)) // 1.5
print(flip3(divideIntegers)(2)(3)) // 1
```

as you can see, it breaks my 'generic' approach. any idea how to solve it?

Comment: For the life of me I cannot see the difference between `flip1` and `flip2`?

Comment: `(/) as (Double, Double) -> Double` will help you grab the correct version of `/`.

Comment: @milos you are right! :-), just skip it, i need some idea how make  flip3 really generic, so flip3(/)(2.0)(3.0) will work .... It is even possible?

Comment: It should be: `func flip3<A, B, C>(f: (A, B) -> C) -> B -> A -> C`

Comment: ... and return `{ b in { a in f(a, b) } }`

Comment: Currying func declaration syntax will be removed from Swift. Halleluja. https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0002-remove-currying.md

Comment: @Darko that is why i define my own currying version ...

Comment: @Darko He is not declaring any. (or you're making a general comment of approval?)

Comment: @user3441734: I am not sure if I understand your question, but something like  `let divideUnknownType = curry(/)` *cannot* compile (as far as I know). At the point where a generic function is *called*, the types must be known to the compiler. That is not the case here because there are many overloaded `/` operators.

Comment: @MartinR yes, and that is my trouble, i don't have any idea, how to solve it. i am not sure, if this could be done, at all

Comment: Martin, I think he was asking about `flip3`, which I answered in the comment  (though he didn't acknowledge that yet)...

Comment: @milos your code will not compile at all (by my best knowledge) ... try it, please, and if it works, publish it as answer.

Comment: I just don't get why such an hard to read and understand construct is needed. Just so that it's fancy functional? There is a reason why they removed this kind of syntax. Milos construct has to be used like this: flip3(/)(2.0)(3.0) For the sake of god - why something strange like this? Additionally I don't understand why the order of the return values is declared as -> B -> A but f is called f(a, b). Is this why it's called "flip"?  flip3(/)(2.0)(3.0) has the result 1.5. But everybody I know would expect the order which creates the result 1.5 should be:  flip3(/)(3.0)(2.0).

Comment: @Darko, this is is not (usually) meant to be called in succession like that `flip3(/)(2.0)(3.0)`. That is not the benefit (clearly). The idea is that you can store partially applied functions for later use...

Comment: @milos Ah, ok, I see. Thanks for the explanation. Well done. +1

Comment: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/introduction-to-function-currying-in-swift  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func flip3<A, B, C>(f: (A, B) -> C) -> B -> A -> C {
    return { b in { a in f(a, b) } }
}

flip3(/)(2.0)(3.0) // 1.5
```

Comment: You are welcome. You've just made a slight error with `f` parameter, which has to take two arguments `(A, B) -> C` to match functions like `/`...

Comment: Yes, i see it now. My head is like hot air balloon ... :-)